# how to get NSURLRequest in UIWebViewDelegate#didFailLoadWithError?

Tags: ios, uiwebviewdelegate

How can we retrieve the `NSURLRequest` that failed to load when the `UIWebViewDelegate` is called back with `didFailLoadWithError` (which gets only the `NSError`) ?  We could stash the `NSURLRequest` when `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` is called, but what if the `UIWebView` is loading multiple requests simultaneously (e.g., a page with scripts, stylesheets, etc.) How do we determine which URL failed to load?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... looks like the `NSError` has a `NSErrorFailingURLKey` key with the URL which is good enough for now... but is there a way to directly get the `NSURLRequest`?

Answer (score 0):

Can you get it from the webView?  webView.request?